# Ej. POO herencia Python

Tags: python, poo, clase, herencia

Necesito que la clase **Marca** herede la clase **Vehiculo**, pero me da un error.

¿Cómo lo puedo realizar?

```
class Vehiculo ():
def __init__(self,color,ruedas,carga,cilindrada,ancho,alto,marchas,asientos,aireacondicionado,arranque,acelera):
    self.color = color
    self.ruedas = ruedas
    self.carga = carga
    self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    self.ancho = ancho
    self.alto = alto
    self.marchas  =marchas
    self.asientos = asientos
    self.aireacondicionado = True
    self.arranque = True
    self.acelera = acelera

def aire(self):
    if self.aireacondicionado == True:
        return("Si")
    else:
        return ("No")



def arrancar (self):
    if self.arranque == True:
        return ("El coche esta encendido")
    else:
        return ("El coche esta apagado")
def arrancar (self):
    if self.acelera == True:
        return ("El coche esta acelerando")
    else:
        return ("El coche esta desacelerando")

def getdatos(self):
    return ("El auto es de color {} , tiene {} ruedas , carga {} , cilindrada {} , ancho {} , alto {} , marchas {} , asientos {} , aire acondicionado{}, arranque {} , acelera {}").format(Vehiculo1.color,Vehiculo1.ruedas,Vehiculo1.carga,Vehiculo1.cilindrada,Vehiculo1.ancho,Vehiculo1.alto,Vehiculo1.marchas,Vehiculo1.asientos,Vehiculo1.aireacondicionado,Vehiculo1.arranque,Vehiculo1.acelera)

Vehiculo1 = Vehiculo("Rojo",4,"400 kg","3000 cc",1.5,2.00,"4 marchas","4 asientos",True,True,False)

print(Vehiculo1.getdatos())

class Marca(Vehiculo):
   def __init__(self,color,ruedas,carga,cilindrada,ancho,alto,marchas,asientos,aireacondicionado,arranque,acelera,marca):
        super().__init__(self,color,ruedas,carga,cilindrada,ancho,alto,marchas,asientos,aireacondicionado,arranque,acelera)
        self.marca = marca
   def getdatos1(self):
            return super().getdatos()+"marca:" + self.marca
Marca1 = Marca("Rojo",4,"400 kg","3000 cc",1.5,2.00,"4 marchas","4 asientos",True,True,False,"Peugeot")

print(Marca1.getdatos())
```

Comment: ¿Nos dirás el error o tendremos que averiguarlo por nuestra cuenta? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y explica el error.

Comment: Si perdon , es este el error  super().__init__(self,color,ruedas,carga,cilindrada,ancho,alto,marchas,asientos,aireacondicionado,arranque,acelera)
TypeError: __init__() takes 12 positional arguments but 13 were given

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la info en la pregunta.. igual el error dice que estas pasando un parametro de mas...

Comment: Estás inicializando el objeto padre con `super()`, así que no necesitas mandarle la referencia (`self`) de la clase hija. En otras palabras, elimina el `self` de `super().__init__(self,color,ruedas,carga ... )`

Comment: Ahí borre eso y me funcionó ahora, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

La solución está mal implementada: no puedes tener un método con 10 variables o más. Es inmanejable. Basta ver el problema que es encontrar el parámetro que sobra o falta en la llamada.

Lo que necesitas es una manera razonable de manejar un objeto que tiene muchos atributos. Una alternativa es usar el módulo [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/dataclasses.html) de Python.

Para usarlo hay que agregar un *decorador* a la clase. El decorador se llama `@dataclass`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Vehiculo:
```

A continuación escribes los atributos usando la sintaxis

```
nombre: tipo [= valor_inicial]
```

El tipo es `int, str, list ...`. Es opcional especificar un valor por default para los objetos.

Entonces, la declaración completa de la clase `Vehiculo` se reduce a:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Vehiculo:
    color: str = "Blanco"
    ruedas: int = 4
    carga: int = 400 # en kg
    cilindrada: int = 3000 # en CC
    ancho: int = 1500 # en mm.
    alto: int = 2000 # en mm.
    marchas: int = 5
    asientos: int = 5
    aireacondicionado: bool = True
    arranque: bool = False
    acelera: bool = False
```

He realizado algunos cambios en los tipos de datos. Para que los atributos sean más útiles, utilice tipos numéricos para representar dimensiones, volúmenes y otras cantidades. También use un tipo booleano para los ítems opcionales. Como strings no tienen mucha utilidad dentro del programa ...

Para imprimir, descarte `getdatos`. No me da la paciencia para escribir esa pesadilla de código. Tampoco es necesario, pues `dataclasses` se encarga de generar `__str__` y otros métodos necesarios.

Lo único que nos queda del código original para la clase es

```
    def arrancar (self):
        if self.arranque:
            return ("El coche esta encendido")
        else:
            return ("El coche esta apagado")

    def acelerar (self):
        if self.acelera:
            return ("El coche esta acelerando")
        else:
            return ("El coche esta desacelerando")
```

Respecto a la clase `Marca`, el mismo tratamiento:

```
@dataclass
class Marca(Vehiculo):
   marca: str = "Hyundai"
```

Entonces, para crear un vehículo o marca, se llama al constructor sin parámetros y luego se cambian los campos que difieren del default:

```
vehiculo1 = Vehiculo()
vehiculo1.color = "Rojo"
vehiculo1.marchas=4
vehiculo1.asientos = 4
vehiculo1.acelera = True

marca1 = Marca()
marca1.color = "Rojo"
marca1.asientos = 4
marca1.marca = "Peugeot"
```

Si esto ocupa muchas lineas, siempre tienes la alternativa de llamar al constructor pasando los parámetros con sus nombres. La siguiente versión

```
vehiculo1 = Vehiculo(color="Rojo", marchas=4, asientos=4, acelera=True)
```

produce el mismo efecto que la anterior. Hay que escoger la que más acomode.

Finalmente, la impresión no requiere nada especial:

```
print(vehiculo1)
print(marca1)
```

produce

```
Vehiculo(color='Rojo', ruedas=4, carga=400, cilindrada=3000, ancho=1500, alto=2000, marchas=4, asientos=4, aireacondicionado=True, arranque=False, acelera=True)
Marca(color='Rojo', ruedas=4, carga=400, cilindrada=3000, ancho=1500, alto=2000, marchas=5, asientos=4, aireacondicionado=True, arranque=False, acelera=False, marca='Peugeot')
```